# Skobbler/Skmaps navigation arrow positioning

Tags: android, skmaps, skobbler-maps

I am using skmaps for my Android application. Route is calculated and is drawn on Map, when navigation starts , the blue circle arrow didnot move along with route(screen doesn't follow the cursor) and soon it was out of view. User have to have to keep adjusting the screen to bring the arrow in view again.

Please help in this.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the "[setFollowPositions](http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/android/3.0.0/com/skobbler/ngx/map/SKMapSettings.html#setFollowPositions(boolean))" flag to true - this way the map will automatically recenter with the user position updates.

For a more complex navigation scenario, check the "Car Navigation UI" example in the demo project.

Comment: Thanks, Please guide how to set it, as i am not able to  setFollowPositions variable to true/false value

Comment: I am not able to find setFollowPositions flag inside SKMapSettings class

Comment: which SDK version are you using? In 3.0.X is should be setFollowPositions, prior to that it was setFollowerMode: http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/android/2.5.1/com/skobbler/ngx/map/SKMapSettings.html#setFollowerMode(com.skobbler.ngx.map.SKMapSettings.SKMapFollowerMode)

Comment: yes i am using 2.5.x one. Please suggest which follower mode should i use? POSITION or POSITION_PLUS_HEADING or NAVIGATION

Comment: Please answer i am using POSITION_PLUS_HEADING but it didnt position arrow in center. @Ando